# How to find out images in GOJS OrgChart-Editor?

Tags: angular, window, nodes, gojs, orgchart

I have used gojs orgchart editor in my code.
Reference : https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgcharteditor.html
I'm facing 3 issues with the init function in angular version.
**1) In function init()**

```
    mouseDrop: function (e: go.InputEvent, node: go.GraphObject) {
                var diagram = node.diagram;
                var selnode = diagram.selection.first();  
                if (mayWorkFor(selnode, node)) {
                  // find any existing link into the selected node
                  var link = selnode.findTreeParentLink();         //Getting error: Property 'findTreeParentLink' does not exist on type 'Part'.
                  if (link !== null) {  
                    link.fromNode = node;
                  } else { 
                    diagram.toolManager.linkingTool.insertLink(node, node['port'], selnode, selnode['port']);
   //Getting error: (parameter) node: go.GraphObject
     Argument of type 'GraphObject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
     Type 'GraphObject' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': invalidateLinkBundle, invalidateConnectedLinks, portSpreading, avoidable, and 170 more.
                  }
                }
              }
```

**2) One If condition in init function**

```
if (window.Inspector) myInspector = new Inspector("myInspector", myDiagram,          //Cannot find name 'myInspector', Cannot find name 'Inspector'
      {
        properties: {
          "key": { readOnly: true },
          "comments": {}
        }
      });
```

**3) I was facing some error in window.Inspector i.e. Property 'Inspector' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'**.
So I have added a Interface in lib.dom.d.ts

```
interface Window{
 Inspector: any;
}
```

But not sure, is it ok if i add anything in lib.dom.d.ts file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript you should be using the TypeScript version of that Inspector extension.  You can use either the one at https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/extensionsTS/DataInspector.ts or the one at https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/extensionsJSM/DataInspector.ts
These are basically the same other than one targeting UMD and the other targeting ES6 modules.

Copy the code into your project.

Comment: Thank you @Walter Northwoods, I resolved some promblems which i have mentioned but still not able to get rid of one error

Comment: `myDiagram.layout.commitNodes = function() {
        go.TreeLayout.prototype.commitNodes.call(myDiagram.layout); 
        myDiagram.layout.network.vertexes.each(function(v) {
          if (v.node) {
            var level = v.level % (levelColors.length);
            var color = levelColors[level];
            var shape = v.node.findObject("SHAPE");
            if (shape) shape.stroke = $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: color, 1: go.Brush.lightenBy(color, 0.05), start: go.Spot.Left, end: go.Spot.Right });
          }
        });
      };`

Comment: In this i have changed **myDiagram.layout.commitNodes**  to **(myDiagram.layout as any).commitNodes** (I'm getting error for previous one so changed).But I don't know how to change this line  **go.TreeLayout.prototype.commitNodes.call(myDiagram.layout);** still getting Property 'commitNodes' is protected and only accessible within class 'TreeLayout' and its subclasses. Can you help me with this?

Comment: It's a **TreeLayout**, isn't it?  So cast it to **TreeLayout**.  And call **super.commitNodes()**.